# AngularJS: How to create routes with ui-router for my application

Tags: html, angularjs, get, href

I have a problem with my `a` tag - I have a page that present data according to the `GET` vars.

For example - /foo.php?opt=1 will show table of cities that each one will go to -  /foo.php?city=4 that have table of schools that go to /foo.php?school=4 that show table of students etc..

The problem is that the first time it works - when I choose city it will show me the list of schools and change the url, but when I choose school, it changes the URL but I still see the city table, and only if I press F5 it will show me table students.

This is the code:

odinvite.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['city']))
{
    include "odbycity.php";
}
else if (isset($_GET['school']))
{
    include "odbyschool.php";
}
else
{
    include "odshowcities.php";
}
?>
```

odshowcities.php:

```
<div ng-controller="allcities">

    <button class="btn btn-info" ng-repeat="x in names">
        <a href="/odinvite.php?city={{x.areaid}}">
        {{x.areaname}}</a>
    </button>

</div>
```

odbyschool.php:

```
<div ng-controller="odbycity">
    <button class="btn btn-info" ng-repeat="x in names">
        <a href="/odinvite.php?school={{x.schoolid}}">
        {{x.school_name}}</a>
    </button>
</div>
```

MyAngular.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.config(function( $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

myApp.controller ('allcities', function ($scope, $http)
{
    $http.get("fetch_json_sql.php?option=1")
        .then(function (response)
        {
            $scope.names = response.data.result;
        });
    console.log($scope.names);
});

myApp.controller ('odbycity', function ($scope, $http, $location)
{
    $scope.cityid=$location.search().city;
    console.log($scope.cityid);
    $http.get("fetch_json_sql.php?option=2&cityid="+$scope.cityid)
        .then(function (response)
        {
            $scope.names = response.data.result;
        });

});

myApp.controller ('odbyschool', function ($scope, $http ,$location)
{
    $scope.schoolid = $location.search().school;
    console.log($scope.schoolid);
    $http.get("fetch_json_sql.php?option=4&schoolid="+$scope.schoolid)
        .then(function (response)
        {
            $scope.names = response.data.result;
        });

});
```

What can be the problem?

I tried to make 100% change of the URL - `<a href="www.google.com">link</a>` and it didn't work. just changed the URL without redirect.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your route configuration.

Comment: @lin  just add it..Thats ok?

Comment: Well m8, AngularJS is for SPA. Its not that easy to combine your routes with an backend directly. You should use ngRoute or uiRouter without having your templates rendered by a backend. I still see no route configuration for `/odinvite.php?school` or `odinvite.php?city`. Your question is "why are my routes not working".

Comment: This is all the code I have...I'm just started to learn AngularJS. What do I need to know about this routes?

Comment: Is that my solution...? - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop rendering your templates with a backend. AngularJS is for SPA. If you need data provided by a backend try to implement an API e.g. a RESTful API. you need to configure your routes for example like in this [runnable demo plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2mOdjM3wswPfkdUVO41b?p=preview). It uses [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). Please note, this is just a demo. You should be able to put your logic into that prototype. I prepared all routes you need by using some dummy data. Just include your existing API in the controllers and you should be fine.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/main");

    $stateProvider
        .state("main", {
            url: "/main",
            templateUrl: "main.html"
        })
        .state("main.listSchools", {
            url: "/listSchools/:schoolId",
            templateUrl: "schools.html"
        }) 
        .state("main.listAreas", {
            url: "/listAreas/:areaId",
            templateUrl: "areas.html"
        });
});


myApp.controller('mainMenuController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.schools = [{
      schoolid: 1,
      name: 'Test School 1'
    },{
      schoolid: 5,
      name: 'Test School 5'
    },{
      schoolid: 11,
      name: 'Test School 11'
    }];
    $scope.areas = [{
      areaid: 3,
      name: 'Test area 3'
    },{
      areaid: 7,
      name: 'Test area 7'
    },{
      areaid: 19,
      name: 'Test area 7'
    }];
});



myApp.controller('listSchoolController', function ($scope, $state) {
  $scope.schoolId = $state.params.schoolId;
});


myApp.controller('listAreaController', function ($scope, $state) {
  $scope.areaId = $state.params.areaId;
});
```

Comment: There is no option to do that without the `Route`? And BTW - I started to read about "app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl" " - Is that the same?

Comment: You could fake the routing but this is not what AngularJS was made for. `ngRoute` is a different route provider. I recommend to use `uiRouter` because its much more flexible and give you a lot of more options to design your routes.

Comment: Ok.. I will need to do some homework to understand what you wrote - altough it looks kind of logical. do you have some recommended site that explain this?

Comment: Hope for some YouTube but thats fine too :) Thanks a lot!!

Comment: BTW - When I using `Route` - there is a chance I'll have to config the server? Because I using a free host server not a dedicated one..

Comment: What do you mean by "config the server" ?

Comment: Do some coding in the root of the server. something I can't do while using free host service...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139676/discussion-between-lin-and-j-doe).